# PHP - doc_root value not taken into account

Tags: php, window, configuration-files

I downloaded the last version of php (currently [php 7.2.8](https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.2)) for a Window 10 desktop, more specifically **the VC15 x64 Thread Safe**.

After defining a shortcut as :

```
C:\Users\c2ll0fd00m\Downloads\php-7.2.8-Win32-VC15-x64\php.exe -c php.ini -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I was able to run perfectly PHP on a small index.php file (in fact just performing a simple **phpinfo()** call.

But after editing the php.ini file and set the value of `doc_root` to another folder like **c:\php\root**, when I launch the php.exe, the command line still displays the old document root value instead of the new one.

More strange, when I let the index.php in the php.exe folder, then the **phpinfo()** shows that the `doc_root` is correctly set with the new value `c:\php\root`.

The consequence if that with the `index.php` file in the `c:\php\root` folder then the url `http://localhost:8000/` is not reachable anymore.

So to summarize this, PHP seems to not take into account the value of `doc_root`.

What should I do?

PS: I already apologize for my english, I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: What do you expect doc_root to do?  This doesn't control where PHP's built in web server serves files from

Comment: Okay so it makes senses. But how may I change the web server files directory then?

Comment: Helps to read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doc_root is not used by the PHP web server

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Use the -t flag to specify a specific directory, or just launch the PHP web server from the directory you wish to use.

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t foo/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answers to what I want! I also read the manual and where the information comes from.